# Inconsistent pandas datetime conversion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

A reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
now = pd.Timestamp('2018-04-09 09:10')
start_of_today = pd.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 0)
print(pd.to_datetime(start_of_today.timestamp(), unit='s'))
```

The last line will return 2018-04-08 22:00:00 instead of 2018-04-09 00:00, why does this happen?

Comment: Is it due to timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per `datetime.timestamp` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

> For aware datetime instances, the return value is computed as:
>
> `(dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)).total_seconds()`

Therefore, you need to align your `pd.datetime` object with UTC timezone:

```
from datetime import timezone
import pandas as pd

now = pd.Timestamp('2018-04-09 09:10')
start_of_today = pd.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 0, 0, 0, 0, timezone.utc)
print(pd.to_datetime(start_of_today.timestamp(), unit='s'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of [datetime.timestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)

it returns `(dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)).total_seconds()`

timezone is utc

You can see

```
In [65]: start_of_today.timestamp()
Out[65]: 1523203200.0

In [66]: pd.Timestamp('2018-04-09 00:00').timestamp()
Out[66]: 1523232000.0
```

Their timestamps are different.